# 404 Not Found when using GOPROXY with JFrog Artifactory

Tags: go, artifactory

A go repository called go-feature is used in Artifactory. Go modules have been uploaded using `jfrog rt gp`. The env var GOPROXY is set to the value provided by Artifactory in the 'Set Me Up' window. All `go get` calls fail with a 404. The Artifactory version is 6.6.1

```
$ go get -v speechmatics.com/cockroachdbingestor@v1.0.1
go: finding speechmatics.com/cockroachdbingestor v1.0.1
go: speechmatics.com/cockroachdbingestor@v1.0.1: unexpected status (http://user:token@fake_artifactory_url.com/speechmatics/api/go/go-feature/speechmatics.com/cockroachdbingestor/@v/v1.0.1.info): 404 Not Found
go: error loading module requirements
```

The speechmatics/cockroachdbingestor module exists in Artifactory with the 1.0.1 version. It can be seen in the web browser.

It was expected that the `go get` would work.

Manually running curl against the URL returns a 404 as well. An Artifactory header is returned so the route to the server works.

Comment: If you curl `http://user:token@fake_artifactory_url.com/speechmatics/go-feature/speechmatics.com/cockroachdbingestor/@v/v1.0.1.info`, does that also 404? That's the generic way to access the same artifact.

Comment: Yes, that also returns 404.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to 6.8.2 `go get` works.

Answer (score 0):

curl `/@v/info` returns valid output, but `/@v/list` gives me 404.

here is the curl for info
curl http://user:api-key@jfrog.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/go/company.com/co/go-pkg/@v/v1.0.0-rc.1.info

and list
here is the curl for info
curl http://user:api-key@jfrog.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/go/company.com/co/go-pkg/@v/list